# Unit Test in Java, using Powermock, how to mock/spy xml parser class private method

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing, powermock

I would like to write unit test a function that calls another private function. This private function is responsible for reading an XML file from disk. However, I want to avoid dependencies on a real file during the unit test. Instead, I would like to use XML content stored in a String variable.

Despite successfully mocking the ScenarioParser, I am encountering an error due to the inner variables DocumentBuilder and DocumentFactory. Therefore, I was considering extending and modifying the unit test accordingly to address this issue.

I am using PowerMockito & JUnit4.

Class which is being tested:

```
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScenarioParser.class);
    
    private final String scenarioFile;
    
    /**
     * Constructs a ScenarioParser with the specified scenario file path.
     *
     * @param scenarioFile the path to the scenario XML file
     */
    public ScenarioParser(String scenarioFile) {
        LOGGER.debug("ScenarioParser Ctor");
        this.scenarioFile = scenarioFile;
    }
    
    /**
     * Parses the scenario XML file and returns a list of Scenario objects.
     *
     * @return the list of parsed Scenario objects
     */
    public List<Scenario> parse() {
        List<Scenario> scenarios = new ArrayList<>();
    
        try(InputStream inputStream = getResourceAsStream(scenarioFile))  
        {
            LOGGER.trace("getResourceAsStream is working for {0}", scenarioFile);
            if (inputStream != null) {
                Document document = parseDocument(inputStream);
                if (document != null) {
                    scenarios = parseScenarios(document);
                }
            } else {
                LOGGER.error("Scenario XML file {} is not found", scenarioFile);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to read the scenario XML file: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
    
        return scenarios;
    }
    
    /**
     * Retrieves the input stream for the scenario XML file.
     *
     * @param scenarioFile the path to the scenario XML file
     * @return the input stream for the scenario XML file
     */
    private InputStream getResourceAsStream(String resourcePath) {
        return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourcePath);
    }
    
    /**
     * Parses the XML document from the input stream.
     *
     * @param inputStream the input stream of the XML file
     * @return the parsed Document object
     */
    private Document parseDocument(InputStream inputStream) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            return builder.parse(inputStream);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to parse the scenario XML file: {}", e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    /**
     * Parses the Document and returns a list of Scenario objects.
     *
     * @param document the scenario element
     * @return the list of parsed Scenario objects
     */
    private List<Scenario> parseScenarios(Document document) {
        List<Scenario> scenarios = new ArrayList<>();
        Element rootElement = document.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList scenarioNodes = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("scenario");
    
        for (int i = 0; i < scenarioNodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node scenarioNode = scenarioNodes.item(i);
            if (scenarioNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element scenarioElement = (Element) scenarioNode;
                String name = scenarioElement.getAttribute("name");
                //...
            }
        }
    
        return scenarios;
    }
    
    /**
     * Parses the step elements within a scenario element and creates ScenarioStep
     * objects.
     *
     * @param scenarioElement the scenario element
     * @return the list of parsed ScenarioStep objects
     */
    private List<ScenarioStep> parseScenarioSteps(Element scenarioElement) {
        List<ScenarioStep> steps = new ArrayList<>();
        NodeList stepNodes = scenarioElement.getElementsByTagName("step");
    
        for (int j = 0; j < stepNodes.getLength(); j++) {
            Node stepNode = stepNodes.item(j);
    
            if (stepNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element stepElement = (Element) stepNode;
                //..
                steps.add(step);
            }
        }
    
        return steps;
    }
    
    /**
     * Parses the parameter elements within a step element and creates a map of
     * parameter key-value pairs.
     *
     * @param stepElement the step element
     * @return the map of parsed parameter key-value pairs
     */
    private Map<String, String> parseStepParameters(Element stepElement) {
        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
        NodeList parameterNodes = stepElement.getElementsByTagName("parameter");
    
        for (int k = 0; k < parameterNodes.getLength(); k++) {
            Node parameterNode = parameterNodes.item(k);
    
            if (parameterNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                Element parameterElement = (Element) parameterNode;
                String key = parameterElement.getAttribute("key");
                String value = parameterElement.getAttribute("value");
                parameters.put(key, value);
            }
        }
    
        return parameters;
     } 
}
```

Following is my test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({ "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.", "javax.xml.", "org.xml.",   "javax.management."})@PrepareForTest({ ScenarioParser.class, DocumentBuilderFactory.class, DocumentBuilder.class })public class ScenarioParserTest {

    @Mock
    private InputStream mockInputStream;
    
    @Spy
    private ScenarioParser scenarioParser = new ScenarioParser("sample.xml"); 
    
    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
       
    }
    
    @Test
    public void testParse_ValidInput_ReturnsScenarios() throws Exception {
        // Mock the input stream with a sample XML content
        String xmlContent = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                "<scenarios>\n" +
                "     <scenario name=\"Scenario 1\" duration=\"10\" interval=\"2\">\n" +
                "       <step action=\"Action 1\">\n" +
                "            <parameter key=\"Param1\" value=\"Value1\" />\n" +
                "            <parameter key=\"Param2\" value=\"Value2\" />\n" +
                "        </step>\n" +
                "        <step action=\"Action 2\">\n" +
                "            <parameter key=\"Param3\" value=\"Value3\" />\n" +
                "        </step>\n" +
                "    </scenario>\n" +
                "    <scenario name=\"Scenario 2\" duration=\"20\" interval=\"3\">\n" +
                "        <step action=\"Action 3\">\n" +
                "            <parameter key=\"Param4\" value=\"Value4\" />\n" +
                "            <parameter key=\"Param5\" value=\"Value5\" />\n" +
                "            <parameter key=\"Param6\" value=\"Value6\" />\n" +
                "        </step>\n" +
                "        <step action=\"Action 4\" />\n" +
                "    </scenario>\n" +
                "    <scenario name=\"Scenario 3\" duration=\"30\" interval=\"4\">\n" +
                "        <step action=\"Action 5\">\n" +
                "            <parameter key=\"Param7\" value=\"Value7\" />\n" +
                "        </step>\n" +
                "    </scenario>\n" +
                "</scenarios>";
    
        // Mock DocumentBuilderFactory and DocumentBuilder
        //DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactoryMock =    
        PowerMockito.mock(DocumentBuilderFactory.class);
        //DocumentBuilder documentBuilderMock = PowerMockito.mock(DocumentBuilder.class); 
       
        //PowerMockito.whenNew(
        //DocumentBuilderFactory.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(documentBuilderF
        //actoryMock);
    
        //PowerMockito.when(
        //documentBuilderFactoryMock.newDocumentBuilder()).thenReturn(documentBuilderMock);
    
        // Mock Document
        //Document documentMock = PowerMockito.mock(Document.class);
        //PowerMockito.
        //when(documentBuilderMock.parse(Mockito.any(InputStream.class))).
        //thenReturn(documentMock);
        // Mock the scenarioElement, scenarioNode, and other necessary objects for testing
    
        // Mock DocumentBuilderFactory and DocumentBuilder
        when(mockInputStream.read(Mockito.any(byte[].class), Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyInt()))
                .thenAnswer(invocation -> {
                    byte[] buffer = invocation.getArgument(0);
                    byte[] contentBytes = xmlContent.getBytes();
                    int len = Math.min(buffer.length, contentBytes.length);
                    System.arraycopy(contentBytes, 0, buffer, 0, len);
                    return len;
                });
    
        // Create the scenario parser and parse the scenarios
        PowerMockito.when(scenarioParser, PowerMockito.method(ScenarioParser.class,     
        "getResourceAsStream", String.class)).withArguments(Mockito.anyString())
                .thenReturn(mockInputStream);
    
                
        //when(scenarioParser, "getResourceAsStream",    
        ArgumentMatchers.anyString()).thenReturn(mockInputStream);
        List<Scenario> scenarios = scenarioParser.parse();
    
        // Verify the parsed scenarios
        assertEquals(2, scenarios.size());
    
        Scenario scenario1 = scenarios.get(0);
        assertEquals("Scenario 1", scenario1.getName());
        assertEquals(10, scenario1.getDuration());
        assertEquals(2, scenario1.getInterval());
    
        List<ScenarioStep> steps1 = scenario1.getSteps();
        assertEquals(2, steps1.size());
        assertEquals("Action 1", steps1.get(0).getAction());
        assertEquals("Value1", steps1.get(1).getParameter("Param1"));
    
        Scenario scenario2 = scenarios.get(1);
        assertEquals("Scenario 2", scenario2.getName());
        assertEquals(20, scenario2.getDuration());
        assertEquals(3, scenario2.getInterval());
    
        List<ScenarioStep> steps2 = scenario2.getSteps();
        assertEquals(3, steps2.size());
        assertEquals("Action 3", steps2.get(0).getAction());
        assertEquals("Value4", steps2.get(1).getParameter("Param4"));
        assertEquals("Value5", steps2.get(2).getParameter("Param5"));
    }

}
```

and this is the pom.xml file partial

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>...<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId><version>2.22.1</version><configuration><argLine>--illegal-access=permit--add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED--add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED--add-opens jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED -Dillegal-access=permit
        --add-exports org.junit.platform.commons/org.junit.platform.commons.util=ALL-UNNAMED
        --add-exports org.junit.platform.commons/org.junit.platform.commons.logging=ALL-UNNAMED
        </argLine>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    ...
```

When executing the test without or with the Maven goal `-Dmaven.surefire.debug test`, I encounter the following error:

> java.lang.VerifyError:Bad type on operand stackException
> Details:Location:javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.newDefaultNSInstance()Ljavax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory;
> @119: invokestaticReason:Type
> 'com/sun/org/apache/xerces/internal/jaxp/DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl'
> (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to
> 'javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory'...

How to fix this issue!

Answer (score 0):

Your code havily enploys *static access* and thus has *tight coupling* with various classes from the java runtime and 3rd party libs. Your difficulties to create mocks is a clear sign of that bad design and the use of PowerMock is a surrender to it.

If you disagree stop reading here.

---

The way to go would be to separate the *instantiation of dependencies* - the objects you want to mock - from your business logic and **inject** them into your *code under test* (cut). The easiest approach is to wrap the static assess in *factory classes*. This classes will be *too simple to fail* so they don't need unittests of their own.

In case the static method called does not have parameters calculatest within your cut you can directly mock its outcome using any other mocking framework beside PowerMock.

In case the static method called does have parameters calculated within your cut  you need to create an mock for this factory and inject it. Of cause you need to configure the factory mock to return a mock of the final dependency...

Comment: I acknowledge the concerns raised regarding the excessive use of static access and tight coupling in the codebase. It's true that such a design can create challenges in writing effective unit tests and can introduce unnecessary complexity.

Comment: In conclusion, I generally agree with the principles you've outlined for enhancing code design and testability. By separating dependencies, adopting dependency injection (DI), and leveraging mocking frameworks, it is possible to achieve loose coupling and improve testability. In this particular scenario, I chose not to use PowerMock. Instead, whenever I encountered difficulties in writing unit tests, I opted to change private methods to the public and then proceeded to write the necessary unit test code. I appreciate the insights shared and thank you for your contribution.